# Cubic equation, calculate squared parenthesis

Tags: cubics

I've been searching all over how to handle this issue I'm sitting with. Hope someone can help me out :)

I have to convert sentence (1) to (6) by removing the quadratic term in (1) with substitution (x = (t - a/3). I feel like I'm doing something wrong when calculation the squared parenthesis when there's a number in front of it as I'm suppose to remove the quadratic term? Can someone please take a look at the calculations and correct me if I'm wrong?

Thanks in advance!

[image over calculations so far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ssbHZ.png)

Answer (score 1):

The substitution $t-\frac a3$ is for a cubic equation of the form 
$x^3 + ax^2 + bx + c = 0.$

In order to make that formula apply to your particular equation,
$x^3 + 1.5x^2 -2.5x + 2 = 0,$
all you need to do (and indeed what you *must* do)
is to set $a=1.5,$ $b=-2.5,$ and $c=2.$

Having done that, you may (and in this case should) make the substitution
$a = 1.5$ *everywhere* where the symbol $a$ occurs.
If you do this, your $x^2$ terms will cancel.

---

You have a transcription error in the coefficient of your linear term, by the way; it was $-2.5$ initially but is later written $+2.5.$

Comment: Thanks for the reply David K.

Does this look right? 
http://i.imgur.com/c8PGmCX.png

Comment: Yes, that looks good. If I were doing it I would probably convert $\frac a3$ from $\frac{1.5}{3}$ to $0.5$ or $\frac12$ right away, but your way also works. Notice that if you add the right sides of equations 3 and 4 now, the $t^2$ terms _will_ cancel, which is the result you should get from this method.

Comment: Hey again David. Can you take a look at the result and confirm if this is correct? 

http://i.imgur.com/3iZugzn.png

Comment: It looks much better. The only thing that didn't look right is the $3.25t$ in formula (7); it looks like you did not account for the term $-1.5t.$